# same vba code results in different graphs being generated

Tags: vba, excel

**Situation**

I have simple VBA code that loops through colum 5-10 and creates graphs with data from row 3-21, sets a title, and sets the value of the x-axis.

**Complication**

the code generates different graphs depending on the column, and stranger yet it generates different graphs from the same column depending on how many times I run the macro.

**Code**

```
Sub Macro6()
For i = 5 To 10
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(21, i))
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = Cells(1, i)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Chart_data!$B$3:$B$21"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I just tested this and its working fine for me, is there any other code working here?

Comment: Only problem I could think of is that you are using just **Range** when you are grabbing source.. For example, if your datas are in **Sheet1** and if **Sheet2** is selected when you are running this macro, it will get completely different data. Try **Sheets("Your Source Worksheet Name").Range(...**

Comment: maybe the whole range `Chart_data!$B$3:$B$21` just hast the formula `=RAND()`... still, `ActiveSheet` may lead to errors and should only be used for testing codes...